# Fixing formatting of table (confidence interval) for Elsevier submission

Tags: tables, journal-publishing, journal

I have a table that I've created using `multicolumn` and `multirow`. This table is for a manuscript I've submitted to Elsevier. Previously I was using the `siunitx` package to add some formatting; however, the journal stripped out quite a bit of the table formatting and it ended up being very malformed in the page proofs. I've been trying to simplify the formatting code; however, I'm a bit stumped about what to do since the Latex instructions for Elsevier provide no guidance about tables.

I'm trying to achieve the most compact representation of this table as possible.

[image: screenshot of table]

This is the current minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llrr@{ (}r@{ to }r@{)}rr}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Stim. design}
        &\multirow{2}{*}{Location}
        &{Freq.}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Mean}}
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{(95\% CI)}}
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability (\%)} \\
    \cline{7-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} 
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(kHz)}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{}
        &{$<\pm$2.5 dB} 
        &{$<\pm$5 dB} \\
    \midrule
    40/s int. ramp & Ocean & 2.8  &                22 &       6 &      40 &           1 &  7 \\
               &       & 5.7  &                23 &      10 &      37 &           0 &  2 \\
               & Land & 11.3 &                26 &      12 &      39 &           0 &  1 \\
               &       & 22.6 &                26 &      10 &      44 &           0 &  2 \\
    80/s int. ramp & Ocean & 2.8  &                19 &       2 &      36 &           4 & 15 \\
               &       & 5.7  &                 8 &      -4 &      21 &          31 & 63 \\
               & Land & 11.3 &                12 &       1 &      25 &          12 & 37 \\
               &       & 22.6 &                21 &       3 &      38 &           2 &  9 \\
    80/s conv. & Ocean & 2.8  &               -23 &     -36 &     -10 &           0 &  2 \\
               &       & 5.7  &               -23 &     -34 &     -12 &           0 &  1 \\
               & Land & 11.3 &               -20 &     -31 &     -10 &           0 &  3 \\
               &       & 22.6 &               -13 &     -27 &       2 &          12 & 33 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I'm fairly certain that a lot of the formatting (such as the `@{ (}`) will get stripped out. I suspect that a simple approach would be to combine the three columns showing the Mean and 95% CI into a single text string `Mean (lb to ub)` so that the journal can't mess up the formatting. However, how do I ensure that the numbers line up properly?

Comment: What was your problem with `siunitx` package? And what is the numbers between brackets (e.g. 2 to 6, 10 to 37)? Are they  errors or ranges? And if they are to be placed in a separate column, why are you inserting brackets around them?

Comment: And where do you want them aligned, e.g. at the first bracket, second bracket, lower limit, upper limit?

Comment: For whatever reason, the formatting I was using with the `siunitx` package did not pass through to the page proofs Elsevier generated for me. So, I'm unclear what I need to do to get the formatting properly done. The numbers between the brackets are the upper/lower bounds of the 95% confidence interval. I'd like the numbers in each of the three columns aligned as closely as possible while ensuring they're compact. The screenshot shows how I'd like it to look; however, it uses Latex commands that end up getting stripped from the page proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three possible solutions, not perfect, but workable. Example 1 is the best in my opinion. I have reduced the `\tabcolsep` and added extra columns to add space between the columns with content. The spaces are added by invisible rules, i.e. they have zero height and depth, see `\rule{4pt}{0pt}`. You may add readability by adding som space between the three group of results, use `\addlinespace[3pt]`. However, you asked for a compact tabular.

I may have misunderstood the connection between the column "Mean" and the "95% Cl". In the revised version of example 1, I have set those as two columns.

I have deliberately not used shortcuts, defined columns etc. but kept the table as simple and standard as possible, so you have better chances to avoid format stripping. You may consider to abbreviate the last heading to "Prob." to shorten it an compact the table even more.

In example 2&3 I have "converted" columns to math columns by piping `$` into the start and end of the column, see `>{$}r<{$}`. Numbers should be set in math columns (as [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sunitx) and [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) do).:

[image]

**Example 1 - extra columns**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lclc r c r c l@{} r c r c r  r @{}}
\toprule
&&&
&\small Freq.
&&&&&&&&&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\small Probability (\% dB)} \\ \cline{14-15}\addlinespace[1pt]
\small Stim. design
&& \small Location
&& \small (kHz)
&& \small Mean
&& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\small 95\% Cl}&
&  \small $<\pm$2.5
&  \small $<\pm$5\\
\midrule

40/s int. ramp &\rule{4pt}{0pt}& Ocean &\rule{4pt}{0pt}&  2.8 &\rule{4pt}{0pt}& 22 &\rule{4pt}{0pt}&(& 6 &to& 40) &\rule{4pt}{0pt}& 1 & 7 \\
               &&       &&  5.7 &&  23 &&(&  10 & to & 37)    &&  0 &  2 \\
               && Land  && 11.3 &&  26 &&(&  12 & to & 39)    &&  0 &  1 \\
               &&       && 22.6 &&  26 &&(&  10 & to & 44)    &&  0 &  2 \\ \addlinespace[4pt]
80/s int. ramp && Ocean &&  2.8 &&  19 &&(&  2 & to &36)     &&  4 & 15 \\
               &&       &&  5.7 &&   8 &&(& \textminus4 & to &21) && 31 & 63 \\
               && Land  && 11.3 &&  12 &&(&  1 & to & 25)     && 12 & 37 \\
               &&       && 22.6 &&  21 &&(&  3 & to & 38)     &&  2 &  9 \\
\addlinespace[4pt]
80/s conv.     && Ocean &&  2.8 && \textminus23 &&(& \textminus36 &to& \textminus10) &&  0 &  2 \\
               &&       &&  5.7 && \textminus23 &&(& \textminus34 &to & \textminus12) &&  0 &  1 \\
               && Land  && 11.3 && \textminus20 &&(& \textminus31 &to & \textminus10) &&  0 &  3 \\
               &&       && 22.6 && \textminus13 &&(& \textminus27 &to& 2) && 12 & 33 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 and 3**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll>{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$} @{}c >{$}r<{$}  >{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$}@{}}
    \toprule

    & 
    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Freq.}
    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Probability (\% dB)} \\
    \cline{6-7}\addlinespace[1pt]
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Stim. design} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Location}    
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(kHz)}
    &\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{{Mean}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{l}{(95\% CI)}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$<\pm$2.5} 
    &\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{$<\pm$5} \\
    \midrule
    40/s int. ramp & Ocean &  2.8 &  22 &  (6 to 40)     &  1 &  7 \\
                   &       &  5.7 &  23 &  (10 to 37)    &  0 &  2 \\
                   & Land  & 11.3 &  26 &  (12 to 39)    &  0 &  1 \\
                   &       & 22.6 &  26 &  (10 to 44)    &  0 &  2 \\
    80/s int. ramp & Ocean & 2.8  &  19 &  (2 to 36)     &  4 & 15 \\
                   &       &  5.7 &   8 &  (--4 to 21)   & 31 & 63 \\
                   & Land  & 11.3 &  12 &  (1 to 25)     & 12 & 37 \\
                   &       & 22.6 &  21 &  (3 to 38)     &  2 &  9 \\
    80/s conv.     & Ocean &  2.8 & -23 & (--36 to --10) &  0 &  2 \\
                   &       &  5.7 & -23 & (--34 to --12) &  0 &  1 \\
                   & Land  & 11.3 & -20 & (--31 to --10) &  0 &  3 \\
                   &       & 22.6 & -13 & (--27 to 2)    & 12 & 33 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}@{}ll>{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$} >{$(}r<{$} >{to}c >{$}r<{)$}  >{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$}@{}}
    \toprule

        & 
        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Freq.}
        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Probability (\% dB)} \\
    \cline{8-9}\addlinespace[1pt]
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Stim. design} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Location}    
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(kHz)}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Mean}}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{(95\% CI)}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$<\pm$2.5} 
        &\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{$<\pm$5} \\
    \midrule
    40/s int. ramp & Ocean &  2.8 &  22 &  6 &   &   40 &  1 &  7 \\
                   &       &  5.7 &  23 & 10 &  &   37 &   0 &  2 \\
                   & Land  & 11.3 &  26 &  12 &  &  39 &   0 &  1 \\
                   &       & 22.6 &  26 &  10 &  &  44 &   0 &  2 \\
    80/s int. ramp & Ocean &  2.8 &  19 &   2 &  &  36 &   4 & 15 \\
                   &       &  5.7 &   8 &  -4 &  &  21 &  31 & 63 \\
                   & Land  & 11.3 &  12 &   1 &  &  25 &  12 & 37 \\
                   &       & 22.6 &  21 &   3 &  &  38 &   2 &  9 \\
    80/s conv.     & Ocean & 2.8  & -23 & -36 &  & -10 &   0 &  2 \\
                   &       & 5.7  & -23 & -34 &  & -12 &   0 &  1 \\
                   & Land  & 11.3 & -20 & -31 &  & -10 &   0 &  3 \\
                   &       & 22.6 & -13 & -27 &  &   2 &  12 & 33 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you can explain the `>{$}`, etc. I will accept  your answer. Thank you!

Comment: This is to turn the figure column to math columns. It is not necessary, but gives a better minus-sign. I am actually working with a better solution, but it will take some minutes (I have to walk my dog).

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\zero}{\phantom{0}}
\newcommand{\plus}{\phantom{+}}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % ensure math mode
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l l C C C C @{} C C @{}}
    \toprule
      \multirow{2}{*}{Stim. Design}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{Location}
      & \mathrm{Freq.}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{Mean}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{95\% CI}
      & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{Probability (\% dB)} \\
      \cline{6-7}\addlinespace[1pt]
      &
      & \mathrm{(kHz)}
      & 
      &
      & <\pm 2.5 
      & <\pm 5 \\
    \midrule
    40/s int. ramp & Ocean & \zero2.8 &     \plus22 & (+06,+40) & \zero1 & \zero7 \\
                   &       & \zero5.7 &     \plus23 & (+10,+37) & \zero0 & \zero2 \\
                   & Land  &     11.3 &     \plus26 & (+12,+39) & \zero0 & \zero1 \\
                   &       &     22.6 &     \plus26 & (+10,+44) & \zero0 & \zero2 \\
    80/s int. ramp & Ocean & \zero2.8 &     \plus19 & (+02,+36) & \zero4 &     15 \\
                   &       & \zero5.7 & \plus\zero8 & (-04,+21) &     31 &     63 \\
                   & Land  &     11.3 &     \plus12 & (+01,+25) &     12 &     37 \\
                   &       &     22.6 &     \plus21 & (+03,+38) & \zero2 & \zero9 \\
    80/s conv.     & Ocean & \zero2.8 &         -23 & (-36,-10) & \zero0 & \zero2 \\
                   &       & \zero5.7 &         -23 & (-34,-12) & \zero0 & \zero1 \\
                   & Land  &     11.3 &         -20 & (-31,-10) & \zero0 & \zero3 \\
                   &       &     22.6 &         -13 & (-27,+02) &     12 &     33 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]